# ScriptTimeoutError: Timed out in protractor-cucumber

Tags: protractor

When i try to run below code for navigation from login page to dashboard, in protractor for , it gives an error "ScriptTimeoutError: Timed out"

```
return expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.equal(url);
element(by.css(".frx-header-username span")).click(); 
element(by.css(".frx-menu-panel span")).click();
```

but when i am giving "browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);" or "browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;" , the code will execute upto checking the url. but it not executing the code for clicking the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `return` in first line. Any line below is omitted. Remove `return`.